# Modelling rotation of angular momentum eigenstate in Python

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, computational-physics, rotation

Consider an angular momentum eigenstate $|j,m \rangle$, what would be the simplest way to model a rotation of this state in Python which starts out in a state where $m = j$ and is acted on by a rotation operator which rotates about the $y$ axis, hence $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{J}_{y}}$.

My idea it to express $|j,m\rangle$ as a column vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{pmatrix}$ and then try to express $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{J}_{y}}$ as a matrix? Hence $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{J}_{y}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{pmatrix} $ $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{pmatrix}$ would given the desired column matrix. What do you think? Do you maybe know how to code this matrix?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about writing code and not about physics per se.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Just leave it for a while!!! It's under 'computational physics' tag.

Comment: [tag:computational-physics] is a tag for asking about algorithms and numerical methods, not for requesting specific code. It's also a bit unclear what exactly your issue is - if you just want to know what matrix corresponds to $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}J_y}$, then that's not a question about computational methods at all, it's just a QM/linear algebra question.

Comment: Moreover these matrices have known analytic form in terms of Jacobi polynomials: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks will review that link. Is my idea of expressing $|j,m\rangle$ as a column vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{pmatrix}$ and then expressing $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{J}_{y}}$ as a matrix fine?

Comment: Right... for small $j$ this will work but the computational overhead grows rapidly as $j$ increases.  If you start with $m=j$ you get an angular momentum coherent state and there are simplified expressions based on the normal ordering of the lowering and raising operators that come handy.  There are also useful recursion relations.  See Wolters, G. F. "Simple method for the explicit calculation of d-functions." Nuclear Physics B 18.2 (1970): 625-653.